# For which $a,b \in\Bbb R$ does there exist the inverse of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

For which $a,b \in\Bbb R$ does there exist the inverse of $A$: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b& b &\ldots &b\\
b& a &b &\ldots&b\\
b& b & a &\ldots &b\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\
b&b& b&\ldots & a
\end{pmatrix}\in M_n$$

So we want to see for which $a,b$ will the $\det(A)\neq 0$ .

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a&b &b  &\ldots &b\\
b& a &b &\ldots&b\\
b& b & a &\ldots &b\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\
b&b& b&\ldots & a
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}a &b &b &\ldots &b\\
b-a& a-b &0 &\ldots&0\\
b-a& 0 & a-b &\ldots &0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\
b-a&0& 0&\ldots & a-b
\end{vmatrix}$$

This is almost a lower triangular matrix, only there should be zeros instead of $b$s in the 1st row. So if I put $b=0$, then I get a lower triangular matrix. The main diagonal will only have $a$s on it, so then $a\neq 0$? Is that it?

Comment: You could calculate the determinant by developing it w.r.t. the last column. Notice that by doing so the factor $(b-a)$ appears. So surely we need that $b\neq a$ which is obvious by just looking at the matrix.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I don't understand what you mean by developing it w.r.t the last column, can you explain?

Comment: There is this recursive way of defining determinant, I meant using that formula w.r.t. the last column of your second matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathrm A = (a - b) \mathrm I_n + b 1_n 1_n^{\top}$$

If $a = b$, then $\mathrm A$ is rank-$1$ and, thus, non-invertible. If $a \neq b$, using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$\det (\mathrm A) = \left(1 + \frac{n b}{a-b}\right) (a-b)^n = (a + (n-1) b) \, (a-b)^{n-1}$$

Thus, if $a \neq b$ and $a + (n-1) b \neq 0$, then $\mathrm A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

1.if a=b, this matrix is not invertible.

2. Add all rows to first.  In first rows now $(n-1)b + a$  at any columns=> if $(n-1)b + a$ - matrix is not invertible

else, we can create upper-triangle matrix without diagonal zeroes

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I don't understand how you got $(n-1)b+a$

Comment: add second row to first, add third row to first ...  
at any column where are one 'a'  and n-1 'b'